# No funciona el método de creación de cuenta Android Studio / Firebase

Tags: java, android, android-studio, firebase

Mira el problema está que no se porque no funciona la creación de cuenta llevo ya un buen rato con el problema intentándolo solucionar y nada, aquí os dejo el ejemplo que tengo del Create account:

```
    private void callesign_up(String email,String password) {


        mAuth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
            .addOnCompleteListener(this, new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                @Override
                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                    Log.d("TESTING", "Sign up sucessfull" + task.isSuccessful());

                    //If sign in falls, display a message to the user. It sign in succeds
                    // the auth state listener will be notified and logic to handle the
                    // signed in user can be handled in the listener.
                    if (!task.isSuccessful()) {
                        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Signed up failed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    } else {
                        userProfile();
                        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Created Account", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        Log.d("TESTING", "Created Account");
                    }
                }
            });
        }
```

LOGCAT: Pestaña de error

```
5-15 21:11:28.054 27023-27023/? E/appproc: Enhanced Zygote ASLR: 
ro.knox.enhance.zygote.aslr != 1. Enhanced Zygote ASLR is DISABLED!
05-15 21:11:28.241 27023-27023/? E/SemAffinityControl: SemAffinityControl: 
registerfunction enter
05-15 21:11:28.986 3161-4129/? E/Watchdog: !@Sync 15106 [2018-05-15 
21:11:28.986]
05-15 21:11:29.265 27042-27042/? E/appproc: Enhanced Zygote ASLR: 
ro.knox.enhance.zygote.aslr != 1. Enhanced Zygote ASLR is DISABLED!
05-15 21:11:29.449 27042-27042/? E/SemAffinityControl: SemAffinityControl:         
registerfunction enter
05-15 21:11:32.236 27056-27056/? E/appproc: Enhanced Zygote ASLR: 
ro.knox.enhance.zygote.aslr != 1. Enhanced Zygote ASLR is DISABLED!
05-15 21:11:32.243 27058-27058/? E/appproc: Enhanced Zygote ASLR: 
ro.knox.enhance.zygote.aslr != 1. Enhanced Zygote ASLR is DISABLED!
05-15 21:11:32.423 27056-27056/? E/SemAffinityControl: SemAffinityControl: 
registerfunction enter
05-15 21:11:32.430 27058-27058/? E/SemAffinityControl: SemAffinityControl: 
registerfunction enter
05-15 21:11:33.187 27081-27081/? E/appproc: Enhanced Zygote ASLR: 
ro.knox.enhance.zygote.aslr != 1. Enhanced Zygote ASLR is DISABLED!
05-15 21:11:33.365 27081-27081/? E/SemAffinityControl: SemAffinityControl: 
registerfunction enter
05-15 21:11:33.456 27093-27093/? E/Zygote: v2
05-15 21:11:33.457 27093-27093/? E/Zygote: accessInfo : 0
05-15 21:11:33.485 27093-27100/? E/art: Failed sending reply to debugger: 
Broken pipe
05-15 21:11:35.487 27093-27093/rs.studenty.studentylanguage 
E/BoostFramework: BoostFramework() : Exception_1 = 
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class 
"com.qualcomm.qti.Performance" on path: 
DexPathList[[],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/system/lib64, /vendor/lib64]]
05-15 21:11:35.666 5017-5017/? E/SKBD: za setCurrentInputModule 
mCurrentInputModule index: 19
05-15 21:11:35.684 5017-5017/? E/SKBD: za setCurrentInputModule 
mCurrentInputModule index: 19
05-15 21:11:35.704 5017-5017/? E/SKBD: get previous
05-15 21:11:37.736 5017-5017/? E/KeyboardInfoUtils: getInstance start
sendSIPInformation state:6  isAbstractKeyboardView : true
05-15 21:11:37.737 5017-27166/? E/KeyboardInfoUtils: sending null 
keyboardInfo as SIP is closed
05-15 21:11:37.807 5017-5017/? E/SKBD: za setCurrentInputModule 
mCurrentInputModule index: 19
05-15 21:11:37.828 5017-5017/? E/SKBD: za setCurrentInputModule 
mCurrentInputModule index: 19
05-15 21:11:40.891 5017-5017/? E/KeyboardInfoUtils: getInstance start
sendSIPInformation state:6  isAbstractKeyboardView : true
05-15 21:11:40.892 5017-27191/? E/KeyboardInfoUtils: sending null 
keyboardInfo as SIP is closed
05-15 21:11:40.963 5017-5017/? E/SKBD: za setCurrentInputModule 
mCurrentInputModule index: 19
05-15 21:11:40.982 5017-5017/? E/SKBD: za setCurrentInputModule 
mCurrentInputModule index: 19
05-15 21:11:44.094 3161-13609/? E/InputMethodManagerService: Perflock object 
null
05-15 21:11:44.097 5017-5017/? E/KeyboardInfoUtils: getInstance start
sendSIPInformation state:6  isAbstractKeyboardView : true
05-15 21:11:44.098 5017-27218/? E/KeyboardInfoUtils: sending null 
keyboardInfo as SIP is closed
05-15 21:11:44.146 5017-5017/? E/SKBD: processWhenPickSuggestionManually : 
32
05-15 21:11:45.073 11025-18394/? E/Volley: [74438] 
BasicNetwork.performRequest: Unexpected response code 403 for 
https://www.googleapis.com/identitytoolkit/v3/relyingparty/signupNewUser? 
alt=proto&key=AIzaSyB5sv1PmXW5F0zytedxMuuCNmaaGggfFqg
05-15 21:11:45.130 11025-18394/? E/Volley: [74438] 
BasicNetwork.performRequest: Unexpected response code 403 
for 
https://www.googleapis.com/identitytoolkit/v3/relyingparty/signupNewUser? 
alt=proto&key=AIzaSyB5sv1PmXW5F0zytedxMuuCNmaaGggfFqg
```

Si alguien podría ayudarme sería genial soy bastante nuevo y no consigo solucionar este error.

Gracias de antemano.

Comment: si miras en el LOGCAT te arroja algún error ? de ser asi agregalo por favor

Comment: Perdona, ¿como puedo pasar el LOGCAT?

Comment: si miras abajo veras una opcion que dice logcat

Comment: Sí lo acabo de ver, ¿te copio todo?

Comment: El eror deberia aparecerte en ROJO esa es la parte imporante

Comment: Primero: 05-15 20:53:22.676 22793-22793/? E/Zygote: v2

Comment: Segundo: 05-15 20:53:22.677 22793-22793/? E/Zygote: accessInfo : 0

Comment: Edite tu pregunta y copua el log cat

Comment: Tercero: 05-15 20:53:25.916 22793-22793/rs.studenty.studentylanguage E/BoostFramework: BoostFramework() : Exception_1 = java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.qualcomm.qti.Performance" on path: DexPathList[[],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/system/lib64, /vendor/lib64]]

Comment: Esos son los tres errores que me aparecen en LOGCAT.

Comment: Copio el log cat entero o solo los errores?

Comment: Mejor copia todo el log eso que pusiste no es el error que estoy . buscandi

Comment: Ya he puesto la pestaña del logcat de error

Answer (score 0):

por favor revise su huella digital SHA1, el problema puede ser con su huella digital SHA1 como se indica aquí

[No funciona el método de creación de cuenta Android Studio / Firebase](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/164613/no-funciona-el-m%C3%A9todo-de-creaci%C3%B3n-de-cuenta-android-studio-firebase)

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28643751/error-403-when-trying-to-sign-in-to-google-game-services-in-android